# RestKit and Bump API - Header Search Paths issue

Tags: ios, header, linker, restkit, bump

I use RestKit in my App and need to link the Bump framework, too.

So, after adding and linking the **libBump.a** and other needed frameworks I get the typical `"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"` and 73 other Mach-O-Linker Errors.

After some tryouts I saw that my Header Search Paths are set to `"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers"`. 
If I take them out (like in the Bump Test Project provided by Bump) it compiles but gives me the error `'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found`

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this issue?